# Is my guppy pregnant......? How do I know how far she is?

Tags: aquarium, fish, pregnancy

I can’t tell if my guppy is pregnant. She keeps floating in one spot and rolling around on the rocks in the tank. She’s also trying to attack the other 2 fish in the tank and her 3 one month old babies. If she is pregnant how do I know how far along she is. I know they are 28-31 days gestational period. But Is There a different way to tell?

[image][image]

Comment: your guppy is very pregnant,the spot in the anal area is black and this is a sign the birth will happen soon,whitin 0-5 days it is not possible to be more exact about when she will give birth.we have had this question many times on this site so i had to mark it as a duplicate.but do a search for pregnant guppy on this site and you will find a lot of information.